# Webdriver using Chrome is slow vs Firefox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using webdriver version 2.48.2 (the latest chrome driver). The test take me about 1.8 sec in Firefox and about 24 sec in Chrome!!
I am using chromedriver.exe version 2.20 (the latest).

I have tried to see that I am not using any proxy running on my computer only.
Try to change the webdriver versions. Installed chrome 32 bit and then 64 bit. There is no affect on the time. I have also tried chromedriver.exe version 2.17.

```
public WebDriver intBrowser(BrowserType browserType) {
    logger.info("init webDriver");
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
    firefoxProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);

    try {
        if (driver == null) {
            File inputFile;
            if (browserType.equals(BrowserType.CHROME)) {
                inputFile = new ClassPathResource("\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe").getFile();
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", inputFile.getCanonicalPath());
                driver = new ChromeDriver(DesiredCapabilities.chrome());

            } else 
                if (browserType.equals(BrowserType.FIREFOX)) {
                driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.info("end init webDriver");
    return driver;
}
```

Comment: The differences in start up time is alarming. I am not sure if extensions run while using chrome driver. See if they do and then consider disabling them.

Comment: i have disabled all the extensions it didn't help

Comment: i have try to run a full scenario and the times difference is the start up time :)  . after that the times are the same